# NoMethodError: undefined method `belong_to' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4:0xa05d2a0>

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So this is kind of baffling me as I can't quite figure out why it's happening. This only happens on my laptop (Ubuntu 11.04), and not elsewhere.  I just seem to have something weird with the setup on this one computer.

I keep getting the following error when I run my specs:

```
be rake spec
```

Gives me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `belong_to' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4:0xb4eb2e4>
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-expectations-2.6.0/lib/rspec/matchers/method_missing.rb:9:in `method_missing'
/home/tom/work/ruby/litdistco-sales/spec/models/sales_item_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:48:in `instance_eval'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:48:in `block in run'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:107:in `with_around_hooks'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:45:in `run'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:294:in `block in run_examples'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:290:in `map'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:290:in `run_examples'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:262:in `run'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `map'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block in run'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:12:in `report'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
/home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@litdistco/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:in `block in autorun'
```

Here are the relevant lines from my spec file that generates the complaint:

```
describe SalesItem do
  it { should belong_to(:publisher) }
  it { should belong_to(:invoice) }
```

I'm running Rails 3.1.0.  Here is ruby -v:

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

Any tips /thoughts/ideas recommendations greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you are missing a gem? Maybe `shoulda`?

Comment: I have shoulda:  /home/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shoulda-2.11.3

Comment: That fact that you have it does not necessarily means that it's loaded. Do you Use gemfile or not? Try to add following in your spec helper p defined?(Shoulda).inspect If you'll got false - shoulda is not properly loaded

Answer (score 30):

Try adding this in your `rails_helper.rb`

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Comment: I added end of rails_helper.rb file. It works. Thanks.

Comment: It work immediately! Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

RSpec core does not have such matcher. It looks like [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers). Just make sure that it's installed and loaded in your spec_helper

Answer (score 5):

I was having a hard time with this for awhile and then changed my spec from:

```
describe ModelName do
  it { should belong_to(:model)}
end
```

to:

```
RSpec.describe ModelName, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:model)}
end
```

and it suddenly worked

Comment: just curious to know, in what condition model can belongs_to itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can write specs like this

```
describe SalesItem do
  describe "Associations" do
    it "belongs_to publisher" do
      assc = described_class.reflect_on_association(:publisher)
      expect(assc.macro).to eq :belongs_to
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this **outside of** this `RSpec.configure do |config| end` in your `rails_helper.rb`

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Try modifying like

```
it { is_expected.to belong_to(:publisher).optional }
```